# typescript - require socket.io syntax to TS

Tags: typescript

```
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: '*',
  }
});
```

How can I change the syntax to TS? (import {} from '';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass parameters to import in ES6 as you're doing with that `require`.

However, the [documentation](https://socket.io/docs/v3/server-initialization/#es-modules) suggest something like this:

```js
import { createServer } from "http";
import { Server, Socket } from "socket.io";

const httpServer = createServer();
const io = new Server(httpServer, {
  // ...
});
```